# Wrong domain with $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-host

I tried to set up an htaccess file, which simply redirects all urls which are unlike one to another url:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com[NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But i recognized something strange, for some reason it results in an endless loop. So i did some tests.

My Webspace looks like this:

```
 -root 
 ---folder 1 
 ---folder 2
```

And i have 2 Domains, one is targeting the root-folder and the other one is targeting a subfolder:

```
-root <--- http://another-url.com
--- folder 1
--- folder 2 <---- http://www.example.com
```

I asume that `%{HTTP_HOST}` from my htaccess file is recognizing every url as the http://another-url.de, which is unlike my www.example.com and so it redirects to www.example.com which of cause results in an endless loop.

I did a simple check: I created a PHP File in my folder 2 which prints the `$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]`.  Opend the file through http://www.example.com and i got the output www.another-url.com.

Does anyone know whats going on? And how i could solve this?!

Comment: Check your vhost configuration, if you're on a shared hosting or something get your host to check it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same issue today in Google Chrome, on a local environment that hosts many fake development domains. Here's what fixed it for me:

- Open the developer tools (Ctrl-Alt-i on PC, Cmd-Option-i on Mac)
- Press and hold the refresh button
- When the options appear, choose `Empty Cache and Hard Reload`

After that, the correct domain loaded. So Chrome must have had a bad DNS entry cached or something.